# Conditional get in Spring framework

Tags: spring, scala, spring-mvc

I am trying to learn Scala using Spring framework. I have to implement conditional get logic in my code. I understand it could be done using etag or Last-Modified option.
Here is my piece of code:

```
 var lastModifiedTime: Long = _;
  @RequestMapping(value= Array("/users/{id}"),method=Array(RequestMethod.GET),headers =    Array("Content-Type=application/json"))
  @ResponseBody
 def getmeth(request: User_details, web: WebRequest): User_details = {             
   if (web.checkNotModified(lastModifiedTime)) {
     return null
   } else {
     lastModifiedTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
   }
```

Could you please help me to fix this code?

Comment: Why are you using `null` instead of `Option`?

Comment: I was actually trying to check if web.checkNotModified(lastModifiedTime) would be true at any point. In that case, it wouldnt display anything. But apparently it never turned true. I am not sure what option should i have instead of null. Could you please enlighten me ?? or can you please share a sample code.

Comment: @rightfold meant [Option](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option) - it's a safer alternative to returning null. You can return either `None` or `Some(User_details)` if you use it and force the client of your method to do necessary checks before using the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I don't know Spring Web.

But according to the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/request/WebRequest.html#checkNotModified(long)) fist of all you should take action if request is modified so you should remove bang (!) from condition. Also lastModifiedTime should be computed from the outside of the getmeth method.

Notice that unlike in Java if statement is an expression and it returns value so you shouldn't use return statement.

As it was said in comment conditional code can be easy and safely done using Scala's Option. In Scala you should always avoid null, as it is hard to distinguish it from incorrect behavior of  your code, and it is very easy to forget or don't know that it is required to write logic dealing with it - you must always read the javadoc (assuming it exists and it is up to date). When you use Option type compiler will force you to deal with "nullability".

```
def getmeth(request: User_details, web: WebRequest): Option[User_details] =            
  if (web.checkNotModified(lastModifiedTime)) {
    None
  } else {
    val userDetails = yourLogic()
    Some(userDetails)
  }
```

Then you can perform an action when option is a Some instance. To do that you can use map method.

```
getmeth(req, web) map { userDetails =>
   userDetails.getName
}
```

---

**EDIT:** @optimus Now when you gave wider scope I see that your method signature is forced by framework and yon can't wrap your value with Option. I think that your problem may be that you update lastModifiedTime on every request so it seems reasonable to me that checkNotModified is always false. I think that you should use that feature only on requests that **not always** update checkNotModified to current time. It becomes pointless otherwise.

Update lastModifiedTime once your resource has become outdated.

Comment: Thanks for the information. The problem I face is that webRequest.checkNotModified(lastModifiedTime) never becomes true.But I could see the response header having information about last-Modified date.Any suggestions??

Comment: Thank you Pawel. Your inputs helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping(value = Array("/users/{user_id}"),method = Array(RequestMethod.GET))
def getUser(@PathVariable("user_id") user_id: String, 
            @Context req : Request ): Any = {

  val u = hm.get(user_id).asInstanceOf[User]
  val tag = u.hashCode().asInstanceOf[EntityTag]
  if (req.getMethod().equals("GET")) {
    val rb : Response.ResponseBuilder = req.evaluatePreconditions(tag);
    if (rb != null)
    {
      rb
    }
    else
    {
      // val u = hm.get(user_id).asInstanceOf[User]
      u
    }
  }
```